# Method cannot be translated into a store expression syntax error

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

I'm using LINQ to Entity and getting error

> Method cannot be translated into a store expression

```
var myStrings = from keys in keyTable
                                       join values in valuesTable
                                           on keys.ID equals values.FK_TableKey
                                       select new NewModel
                                       {
                                           Value = values.Value,                                        
                                           Hash = CalculateHash(string.Format("{0}_{1}", keys.Key, keys.Context))
                                       };
```

//I tried to convert in into LINQ syntax like below

> //How to calculate Hash value which will work on LINQ to Entity?

//Method

```
 public string CalculateHash(string input)
        {
            if (input == null)
                return null;
//calculate MD5 hash
            var md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
            byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
            byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes); 

            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (byte t in hash)
                sb.Append(t.ToString("P2"));

            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: This is not possible you will have to call ToList() before calculating hash.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya is that the same shown in below answer ? please elaborate ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since hash value should be computed on the .NET side, you can add `AsEnumerable()` call after the portion that produces the "raw data", and then compute the rest outside your RDBMS, like this:

```
var rawStrings = from keys in keyTable
                join values in valuesTable
                on keys.ID equals values.FK_TableKey
                select new {
                    Value = values.Value,                                        
                    keys.Key,
                    keys.Context
                };
var myStrings = rawStrings.AsEnumerable().Select(t => new NewModel {
     Value = t.Value,
     Hash = CalculateHash(string.Format("{0}_{1}", t.Key, t.Context))
});
```

The first query runs on the RDBMS side, and produces the key and the context for computing the `Hash`. The second query uses the raw data to compute the desired output.

Comment: `Value` does not exist in current context in `myStrings` :(

Comment: aha my bad sorry and thanks but one more question what about my model? as in question I tried to bind values `NewModel` because i have taken this model class and properties are there inside this.

Comment: I tried given model after new but getting error : `string 'a.Value , invalid initializer member decelerator `

Comment: i missed Value= t.value :) thanks  a ton , is there any other way to do so? can you also give me any link and thread to understand all above stuff ? for detail programming :)

Comment: @ashish [Here is a nice discussion of `IEnumerable<T>` vs. `IQueryable<T>` and using `AsEnumerable()` to switch from `IQueryable<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>`. You can do it in a single query, but unfortunately `AsEnumerable` does not go well with query syntax, and `Join` does not go well with fluent syntax, so doing it this way is probably the most readable. It is pretty much as efficient as it gets, too, because query execution is deferred, meaning that no extra storage is taken for intermediate results.